# Why threads continue to run after a cancel has been called?

Tags: c#, linq, parallel.foreach, cancellation-token

Consider this simple example [code](https://github.com/ShaharShokrani/ParallelProgramingDotNet/blob/master/ParallelProgrammingDotNet/CancellationAndExceptions.cs):

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var items = Enumerable.Range(1, 20);

var results = items.AsParallel().WithCancellation(cts.Token).Select(i =>
{
    double result = Math.Log10(i);                
    return result;
});

try
{
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        if (result > 1)
            cts.Cancel();
        Console.WriteLine($"result = {result}");
    }
}
catch (OperationCanceledException e)
{
    if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        Console.WriteLine($"Canceled");
}
```

Foreach of the results in the parallel results it prints the results until `result > 1`

This code output is something like:

```
result = 0.9030899869919435
result = 0.8450980400142568
result = 0.7781512503836436
result = 0
result = 0.6020599913279624
result = 0.47712125471966244
result = 0.3010299956639812
result = 0.6989700043360189
result = 0.9542425094393249
result = 1
result = 1.0413926851582251 <-- This is normal
result = 1.2041199826559248 <-- Why it prints this value (and below)
result = 1.0791812460476249
result = 1.2304489213782739
result = 1.1139433523068367
result = 1.255272505103306
result = 1.146128035678238
result = 1.2787536009528289
result = 1.1760912590556813
result = 1.3010299956639813
Canceled
```

**My question is why it continue printing values over 1?** I had expected that it the `Cancel()` token will be terminate the process.

---

Update 1

[@mike-s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59075734/6844481)'s answer suggested:

> It's also useful to check a cancellation token inside a loop (as a
>   means to abort the loop) or before a long operation.

I've tried adding a check

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
    if (result > 1)
        cts.Cancel();

    if (!cts.IsCancellationRequested) //<----Check the cancellation token before printing
        Console.WriteLine($"result = {result}");
}
```

It still gives the same result's output.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> My question is why it continue printing values over 1?

Imagine you hired a hundred pilots to fly a hundred planes from a hundred airports. A bunch of them take off, and then you send a message saying "cancel all the flights".  Well, there are a bunch of planes *on the runway at takeoff speed* when you send that message, and the message arrives *after they are in the air*. Those flights will not be cancelled!

You are discovering the most important thing to know about multithreaded programming. **You have to reason as though every possible ordering of things happening might occur**. That includes messages arriving later than you think they should.

In particular, your problem is a result of your abuse of the parallelization mechanisms, which are designed to parallelize *long work*. *You've created a bunch of tasks that take less time to run than it takes to send the message stopping them.* It should not be a surprise in that case that some of the tasks complete after they've been told to stop.

> I expected that calling Cancel() on the token would terminate the process.

Your expectation is completely, totally wrong.  Stop expecting that, since that expectation in no way conforms to reality.  A cancellation token is a request to cancel an operation as soon as it is convenient to do so. It's not terminating a thread or a process.

However, even if you *did* terminate the threads, you would still observe this behaviour.  Thread termination is an event like any other, and that event is not instantaneous. It takes time to execute, and other threads can continue their work while that thread termination is executing.

> what do you mean by "convenient" in "a request to cancel an operation as soon as it is convenient to do so"?

Let's take a step back.

If the work to be done is *extremely short*, then there is no need to represent it as a task. Just do the work! In general if work takes less than about 30ms, just do the work.

Therefore, let's assume that every task *takes a long time*.

Now, why might a task take a long time? There are generally two reasons:

- We're waiting for another system to complete some task. We're waiting for a network packet or a disk read or some such thing.
- We have a huge amount of computation, and the CPU is saturated.

Suppose we are in the first situation. **Does parallelizing help?** No. If you are waiting for a package in the mail, *hiring one, two, ten or a hundred people to wait does not make the package come faster*.

But that *does* help for the second case; if we have an extra CPU in the machine we can dedicate *two* CPUs to solve the problem in about half the time.

Therefore we can assume that *if we are parallelizing a task, it is because the CPU is doing a lot of work*.

Great.  Now, what is the nature of "CPU does a lot of work?"  It almost always involves a *loop* somewhere.

So then, how do we cancel a task?  We do not cancel a task by *terminating the thread*. We *ask* the task to cancel itself. A well-designed task will take a cancellation token, and *in its loop* will check to see if the cancellation token is indicating that the task is cancelled.  **Cancellation is cooperative**.  The task has to *cooperate* and *decide when it checks to see if it is cancelled*.

Notice that *checking to see if you are cancelled* is *work*, and that is work that *takes time away from the real task*.  If you spend half your time checking to see if you are cancelled, your task takes twice as long as it could. And remember, the point of parallelizing the task is *to make it take half as long*, so *doubling* the amount of time it takes to do the task is a non-starter.

Therefore most tasks do *not* check every time through the loop if they are cancelled. A well-designed task will check every few milliseconds, not every few nanoseconds.

That's what I mean by "a cancellation is a request to stop when it is convenient". The task, if it was written correctly, should know what a good time to check for cancellation is so that it balances responsiveness against performance.

Comment: Hey @eric-lippert, `as soon as it is convenient to do so` - what do you mean by convenient? when it will actually going to happen?

Comment: @ShaharShokrani: That's up to the code which accepts a `CancellationToken`.  Such code can use `IsCancellationRequested`, `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`, or `Register` to stop further work.  In the case of network APIs, it's normal to stop work mid-request.  In the case of APIs which accept a delegate (e.g., the Task Parallel Library), they usually cancel when requesting the next work item.  It's up to you to indicate if it is convenient to cancel a partial work item (e.g., by calling `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` in the work item); third-party libraries have no way of knowing.

Answer (score 4):

Cancel() on a cancellation token is just signaling the cancellation token, which just impacts other places in the code that check the token (such as calls to cts.IsCancellationRequested). Framework calls often will check the cancellation token and abort. It's also useful to check a cancellation token inside a loop (as a means to abort the loop) or before a long operation.

The cancellation token does not forcibly terminate a thread or process.  There are other APIs for that, such as [Environment.Exit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Hey @mike-s thanks for the answer, I have not checked the `Environment.Exit` yet but see please updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Eric's excellent answer ... "a thread or process" and "a unit of work" usually should not be the same thing.  Creating a thread to carry out one unit of work and then die is like shooting flaming arrows into the air:  you can't control it, can't predict it, and those arrows start interfering with each other.  The system becomes choked with so much work that it can't work on anything.  (A condition called *"thrashing."*)

A much better strategy is modeled after a fast-food restaurant:  a small number of workers, each with an assigned task, taking work-requests from a queue and delivering the finished sandwiches to another.  At any instant, any queue might contain more or fewer entries.  You don't see any of the workers falling down, dead.  During lunch rush-hour, more workers are busy but at the same tasks.  During a slow period they remain at their posts, patiently waiting for the next order to arrive.  Any particular work-request might be flagged as "cancelled," and the workers notice this and respond accordingly.  No part of the restaurant is "over-committed," and the entire operation is able to consistently produce a predictable number of sandwiches per hour, according to management control.